# List of all z/OS DD statements in JCL job using JZOS toolkit

Tags: java, zos, jcl

Is it possible to find a list of all DD statements defined for a given step using z/OS JZOS Java toolkit ?

I can get information about specific DD statements by name using `ZFile.readJFCB` method, but I did not find any method which would list all DD statements.

Is it possible to do it using C/C++ API and JNI?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to get the list of DD statements allocated to your jobstep.

The typical way this is done would be by scanning through a z/OS data structure called the "Task I/O Table", or TIOT. The TIOT contains an entry for every currently allocated DD statement, including concatenated files and so forth.

This is usually a task for mainframe assembler language, but you can do it in C (or Java) if you're not averse to juggling pointers. What I'd do is run IBM's "C DSECT" utility that converts assembler language data structures into C structures so that you can include them in your C program. In addition to the assembler mapping macro for the TIOT (it's IEFTIOT1), you'll need the "Task Control Block" (TCB - macro IKJTCB) and possibly the "Prefixed Storage Area" (PSA - IHAPSA).

When your application code is running, absolute location 0 is the PSA, and label PSATOLD points to the last dispatched TCB - that would be your running task. In the TCB is a pointer to the TIOT - TCBTIO. Thus, a few lines of C get you to the start of the TIOT.

The TIOT has a prefix, so you want to get to the label "TIOENTRY"...there's one of these for each allocated file. In it, you'll see TIOEDDNM - the DDNAME (or blanks, for concatenated files), so if you just iterate through the TIOENTRY structures, you can collect up all the DDNAMEs.

There are a few small details I'm skipping - you'll want to verify the TIOENTRY structures to make sure they aren't "free space" entries (this is common in TSO) and you'll need to know that TIOELNGH has the TIOENTRY length that you add to the TIOENTRY to get to the next one. And once you're comfortable scanning the TIOT as I've described, you'll find that it points to all the structures you might need to determine pretty much any characteristic of a given file.

Comment: Great answer! You can chase the PSA/TCB/TIOT control blocks in pure Java using fixed offsets and the [JZOS ZUtil.peekOSMemory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.70.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZUtil.html#peekOSMemory(long,%20byte%5B%5D)) method. There's an example [here](https://github.com/zsystems/java-samples/blob/master/PeekOSMemory.java).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JZOS documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.70.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.html) it is not possible. 
But why would you need it?

You cannot handle all possible DD statements in your program. You should expect just specific ones. If you want to pass dynamic amount of DD statements (several input files), you can use pre-defined names.

For example:

```
//INPUT01 DD DSN=...  
//INPUT02 DD DSN=...
```

and in your Java code you can create a loop to check if INPUT01-99 exist -> then use it.

Comment: The Java-based system replaces a legacy one. In the old system, an end-user was able to add an arbitrary DD statement and the program was able to discover the name and use it. I can not provide more details on how it was done, just do not know. I assume it was done through some kind of low level C API.